# Silverlight 4 crashing every browser (SL3 doesn't)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-plugin

I am testing my application on a number of machines. It is fine on every machine except 1.

I'm having problems with one XP machine where in `internet explorer`, `chrome` and `firefox` the Silverlight plugin crashes on EVERY page with Silverlight.

Pages that used to work fine with silverlight 3 crash instantly - including my app and the [Silverlight Beta 4 demo page](http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html)!!! The browser crashes instantly and doesn't even attempt to load the page.

I don't know how to debug this because there's no error. It just crashes instantly in all these browsers. 
Reinistalling, rebooting didn't fix the problem.

Comment: it was. uninstalling and rebooting didn't fix it though :-(

Comment: I have the exact same problem on a fresh Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.  My app loads, then hangs for a while, and ultimately crashes the browser.  I'm trying to hit a Silverlight 3 app with the Silverlight 4 runtime.

Comment: @steve in all browsers? SL3 and SL4 apps for me both break. i think thats what you're saying too. obviously you're 64 bit so i'm wondering if that is a factor in your situation. i'm definitely 32 bit though. relatively old machine

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried Firefox or Chrome yet, only IE.  I'll try Firefox today and post my findings back.  Thanks for the info on the SL4 apps breaking.  That is reason enough to compile the application in SL4 just yet (assuming Firefox and Chrome break for me like they did for you).

Comment: Chrome crashed, but Firefox did not.  I should have also mentioned that even IE doesn't crash ALL the time (just most of the time).  Odd.

Comment: @steve did the RC fix this for you?

Comment: Yes!  I'm happy to say that it did.  Looks like the RC is a lot more stable for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it might be, but you could try debug it this way.

1. Attach to running instance of Firefox with Visual Studio.
2. Go to menu Debug -> Exceptions... and check all "Break when exception is" boxes.
3. Now open page that crashes the browser.

Ideally you should catch an exception with debugger. I've spotted this way `OutOfMemoryException` in my app. Browsers were crashing with no reason, but debugger showed the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in RC/RTM (at least for me!)